# Actions on Google Node.js SDK unicode

Tags: node.js, unicode, google-assistant-sdk

How do I very simply show a Euro symbol in Google Assistant? Every time that I attempt to I get the symbol in a different encoding. What simple thing am I missing?

actions-on-google SDK version 2.0.1

```
const { dialogflow } = require('actions-on-google')

const app = dialogflow({ debug: true })

app.intent('euro-intent', (conv) => {
  console.log('€')
  conv.ask('€')
})

exports.myBot = app
```

My action is calling a webhook on AWS API Gateway that is connected to a Lambda function using Node.js v 8.10. The CloudWatch logs show

```
{
    "payload": {
        "google": {
            "expectUserResponse": true,
            "richResponse": {
                "items": [
                    {
                        "simpleResponse": {
                            "textToSpeech": "€"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "userStorage": "{\"data\":{}}"
        }
    },
    "outputContexts": [
        {
            "name": "projects/newagent-9bde7/agent/sessions/1525808242247/contexts/_actions_on_google",
            "lifespanCount": 99,
            "parameters": {
                "data": "{}"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

However, I get the below in the simulator.

[image: euro]

Comment: Can you try returning `"\\u20ac"` instead of `€` and see if it helps

Comment: @TarunLalwani This returns the characters "\u20ac" and the assistant reads it as "you twenty ack".

Comment: I think this may be a encoding issue then. I would look at the headers and make sure `Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8` is being returned, if not then return the `content-type` header with the `charset` in your lambda. Another thing i would try is setting the content handling to convert to text if needed. I have not used it but not sure it would changing anything for you, https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMKTB.png

Comment: Did you get chance to try these things?

Answer (score 3):

In your webhook, use unicode for *EURO SIGN*. The unicode for *EURO SIGN* is ***U+20AC***

In your **Node.js implementation**, use **'\u20ac'** notation.

In a string value, '\u' notation indicates that value is a unicode character denoted by four hex digits.

Here is the version with unicode value:

```
const { dialogflow } = require('actions-on-google')

const app = dialogflow({ debug: true })

app.intent('euro-intent', (conv) => {
  console.log('\u20ac')
  conv.ask('\u20ac')
})

exports.myBot = app
```

Comment: This returns exactly the same "â¬" characters.

Comment: I've tried this on my webhook and running. It's deployed to firebase. I checked both in my phone and on simulator. What are you seeing when you run console.log('\u20ac') at online editor: https://repl.it/repls/MelodicWillingFunction

Comment: I see the Euro symbol in the online editor. Perhaps it is something with the way AWS is returning the payload? I am not using Firebase, but using AWS API Gateway and a Lambda function.

Comment: Maybe you can also try to use escape with ES6 way: \u{20ac} @duffn